# Table Is Busy?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Short Time Ago, I Asked A Question About Sorting A Table And Mr. [Tim Jarvis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10387/tim-jarvis) Answered Me Nice. I Searched The Keywords Given By Him And Found This Procedure In [This Site](http://info.borland.com/devsupport/bde/bdeapiex/dbisorttable.html). But When I Used This Procedure The Error "Table Is Busy" Raised.
How Can I Solve This Problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Why I Received 2 Negative Votes??!! did I Do Something Wrong??!!

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes are because it's hard to take a question seriously when every word is capitalized.  http://www.pvc.maricopa.edu/lsc/faq/eng/enggragen.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Found The Answer By Myself, Without The Help Of Those Voted Me Down!!!! 
This Error Happens When The Table You Are Coding For, Is Using By Another Program And In This Case It Was 'Delphi IDE', Because Table Was Active At Design Time(And IDE Was Accessing To Database As An Independent Application). I Set It To False And Instead Added Active Code To Form Create.